# I have hundreds of dependencies on my package.json file which I didn't install (npm and using Warp)

Tags: npm, dependencies, warp-terminal

I'm taking an online course on website development and ran into issues setting up dependencies using npm. The course materials are a few years old, so many dependencies are outdated, causing headaches. Strangely, my package.json file in VS Code is filled with hundreds of dependencies when there should only be like 5-10. The devDependencies section is fine though, as I installed those intentionally. I suspect if Warp, the iOS terminal tool I'm using, might have automatically installed these extra dependencies. Here's a list of my active devDependencies, some of which are outdated, in case that these somehow installed all the other dependencies, which I'm sharing a few since I have loads of them. Any help on fixing this mess would be appreciated, since I've got tons of dependencies now on my project and I have no clue how to fix this. Thanks!

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^12.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "imagemin": "^8.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.8.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.71.0",
    "sass-loader": "^14.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
    "webpack": "^5.90.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.10.0"
},
"main": "webpack.config.build.js",
"dependencies": {
    "accepts": "^1.3.8",
    "acorn": "^8.11.3",
    "acorn-import-assertions": "^1.9.0",
    "ajv": "^6.12.6",
    "ajv-formats": "^2.1.1",
    "ajv-keywords": "^3.5.2",
    "ansi-html-community": "^0.0.8",
    "ansi-regex": "^6.0.1",
    "ansi-styles": "^6.2.1",
    "anymatch": "^3.1.3",
    "arg": "^5.0.2",
    "array-flatten": "^1.1.1",
    "array-union": "^1.0.2",
    "array-uniq": "^1.0.3",
    "balanced-match": "^1.0.2",
    "batch": "^0.6.1",
    "binary-extensions": "^2.2.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "bonjour-service": "^1.2.1",
    "brace-expansion": "^2.0.1",
    "braces": "^3.0.2",
    "browserslist": "^4.23.0",
    "buffer-from": "^1.1.2",
    "bundle-name": "^4.1.0",
    "bytes": "^3.0.0",
    "call-bind": "^1.0.7",
    "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30001587",
    "chokidar": "^3.6.0",
    "chrome-trace-event": "^1.0.3",
    "clone-deep": "^4.0.1",
    "color-convert": "^2.0.1",
    "color-name": "^1.1.4",
    "colorette": "^2.0.20"
}
```